# ":ssh" ins't available in a Phoenix application

Tags: ssh, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix web application I'm using the Erlang :ssh module, here's a part of my code:

```
# my_app/lib/file1.ex

# ............
:ssh.start()
```

Locally it works, but on a server it throws an exception for some reason, **I can see that in the logs** and the console it throws the exception also:

```
# in Phoenix console as well

> :ssh.start()
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :ssh.start/0 is undefined (module :ssh is not available)
    :ssh.start()
```

And

```
$ sudo apt-get install erlang-ssh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
erlang-ssh is already the newest version (1:19.2-1
```

Comment: Are you able to run `ssh:start().` in `erl`?

Comment: @Dogbert, `ssh:start().
* 3: syntax error before: '.'
`

Comment: @Dogbert, `ssh:start().` ---> `* 3: syntax error before: '.'`

Comment: @Dogbert, actually -- yes, I'm able to. `ssh:start().` ---> `ok`

Comment: How are you starting the Phoenix console? Is that just `iex -S mix` or a release created by exrm or similar?

Comment: @Dogbert, the 2nd option.

Comment: Try adding `:ssh` as a dependency to `applications` list in your mix.exs, create a new release, upload, and then run `:ssh.start` in console.

Comment: @Dogbert, thnks, I'll try to.